# Is it possible to fetch data other than the default user data from Facebook API

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a problem when I am trying to fetch data like the `Home town` for user ans I found the below error:

[image]

Also I want to fetch another data like:

- Getting user basic information (Username, number of Friends and
  followers (if available), etc..)
- Getting Friends names
- Posts

So is it possible to fetch those data? as I tried to fetch them I found the same error...

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_facebook_login/flutter_facebook_login.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert' as JSON;
import 'dart:io' as Io;


void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return _MyAppState();
  }
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  bool _isLoggedIn = false;
  Map userProfile;
  final facebookLogin = FacebookLogin();

  _loginWithFB() async {
    final result = await facebookLogin.logIn(['email']);

    switch (result.status) {
      case FacebookLoginStatus.loggedIn:
        final token = result.accessToken.token;
        final graphResponse = await http.get(Uri.parse(
            'https://graph.facebook.com/v10.0/me?fields=id,name,picture,email,name_format,birthday,hometown&access_token=${token}'));

        final profile = JSON.jsonDecode(graphResponse.body);
        print(profile);
        setState(() {
          userProfile = profile;
          _isLoggedIn = true;
        });
        break;
      case FacebookLoginStatus.cancelledByUser:
        setState(() => _isLoggedIn = false);
        break;
      case FacebookLoginStatus.error:
        setState(() => _isLoggedIn = false);
        break;
    }
  }

  _logout() {
    facebookLogin.logOut();
    setState(() {
      _isLoggedIn = false;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
            child: _isLoggedIn
                ? Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Image.network(
                  userProfile["picture"]["data"]["url"],
                  height: 100.0,
                  width: 100.0,
                ),
                Text(userProfile["id"]),
                Text(userProfile["name"]),
                Text(userProfile["email"]),
                Text(userProfile["name_format"]),
                Text(userProfile["birthday"] ?? 'Birthday: empty'),
                Text(userProfile["hometown"] ?? 'Hometown: empty'),
                OutlinedButton(
                  child: Text("Logout"),
                  onPressed: () {
                    _logout();
                  },
                ),
              ],
            )
                : Center(
              child: OutlinedButton(
                child: Text("Login with Facebook"),
                onPressed: () {
                  _loginWithFB();
                },
              ),
            )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I searched for this, I found that Facebook have changed the policy for V2, is that true?

I hope someone could help me and give me a solution for this :)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the flutter_facbook_login is just doing the OAuth login process and it is generating the access token for you so with that access token you could use the Facebook Graph API to access lots of things but first, u should get permission to those things when you attempting the login
for example in your code

```
 facebookLogin.logIn(['email']);
```

you are getting the permission to access users email

read the Facebook document it describes everything you need to know

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/version2.12/

Comment: first thanks for your answer, so as I under stand from your answer it's possible to get other info like posts, friends, followers, etc....?

So if it could be could you show me how can Implement this related to my code, because I tried to fetch those data, and didn't get any infos :)

Comment: @MahmoudHarooney read the first document I included in the previous answer and after that read this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/permissions/reference in short yes u can access but first, your app should be reviewed by Facebook

Comment: @MahmoudHarooney create a facebook developer app, request for permission according to requiremnet, use graph api explorer for apis, read the docs about api endpoints. thats all:)